# How to Exclude Hard Drives and Folders from Spotlight Index in Mac OS X PERMANENTLY?

Tags: mac, spotlight

I found an article that shows how to exclude external drives from Spotlight indexing [HERE](https://osxdaily.com/2011/12/30/exclude-drives-or-folders-from-spotlight-index-mac-os-x/), which is completely useless if you have to do it every single time when you plug back in the external drive.

Is there any way to prevent spotlight indexing AT ALL TIMES on EVERY EXTERNAL DISK either new disk or previous used disk or whatever...?

Comment: So you want to prevent Spotlight from ever indexing any external disk, even disks which haven't been connected to your Mac yet?

Comment: Yes. Ideally, uninstalling spotlight would be the best, no?

Answer (score 1):

A quick test shows that an external drive's exclusion will still be remembered when the drive is removed and then re-plugged in.

You'll find various other methods on these questions:

[How to stop OS X from writing Spotlight and Trash files to memory cards and USB sticks?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/6707/how-to-stop-os-x-from-writing-spotlight-and-trash-files-to-memory-cards-and-usb)

[Prevent Spotlight from indexing external drive](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/273162/prevent-spotlight-from-indexing-external-drive)

[Avoiding Spotlight to spin up external drive](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/321995/avoiding-spotlight-to-spin-up-external-drive)

Though these all require intervention on each drive.